# Integration method which works as ode solver Python3

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, integration, ode

I was wondering if it's there a Python function for cumulative integration which works just as an ode solver, making the loop for you.

I'm trying scipy.integrate.cumtrapz but it takes as input an already defined array for the integrating variable y. I would like to define my integrating function inside a function to be called at every iteration of the integral. Is there a way to avoid for/while loop for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what your problem is and what you want the solution to be like, ideally with some illustrative input and output. Also, please specify what’s wrong with existing ODE solvers (which exist in SciPy after all).

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain what's my need.
Let's take as example the calculation of the integral part of a PI controller.
Let's suppose that the reference signal is:

```
ref = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
```

Measured signal is the output of a physical model (solution of a differential equation). To keep code simple let's assume that:

```
meas = amp/2*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
```

What is important is that meas is logically defined after the calculation of the output of the PI controller, i.e. after finding the integral part.

I'm trying to do like this:

```
from scipy import integrate
amp = 1
freq = 100
setpoint = [amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*0)]
meas = [0]
err = [0]

def integral():
    global setpoint, meas, err
    setpoint.append(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time))
    print(meas[-1])
    e = setpoint[-1] - meas[-1]
    err.append(e)
    meas.append(amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time))
    return e

intg = integrate.cumtrapz(integral(), time, initial=0)
```

but what I get at the output is only the integral of ref.
If I print meas[-1] inside the function, it retrieves [0], so the function integrate.cumtrapz is calling integral() only one time.

I want to avoid for loops and find a way of making the integral with an optimized function which makes the loop for me.
Such a function should work like an ode solver, for example:

```
def dydt(t,y): return 2*y
time = np.arange(0,1,1e-3)
sol = solve_ivp(dydt, [0,1], [1], t_eval = time)
y = sol.y[0]
```

In this case solve_ivp calls function dydt every time it needs and then gives solution with respect to a defined time axis.